# Common form with dropdown list for both create and edit views in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dropdown

In my blade view I am using the same form for both create & edit views. I've included select options within my Form like below. When I edit, the item will be selected automatically according to the codes. But when I'm in create mode, I'll get an error about department id from $ask->department->id which is

> Error of
> "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object".

I'm using "ViewComposer" facility to generate dropdown list items. It seems no errors according to other answers in several forums as same to this one. But there are errors as mentioned above. Can anyone explain what it is?

> Methods in controller

```
public function create()
{
    $ask = new Ask();
    $ask->load(['department']);
    return view('pages.ask.create', compact('ask'));
}

public function edit(Ask $ask)
{
    $ask->load(['department', 'machine', 'type']);
    return view('pages.ask.edit', compact('ask'));
}
```

> DepartmentComposer.php

```
 namespace App\Http\View\Composers;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Department;

class DepartmentComposer
{
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('departments', Department::select('id', 'department_name')->orderby('department_name', 'asc')->get());
    }
}
```

Dropdown in form

```
<select name="department_id" id="department_id" class="form-control">
    <option disabled selected>Select Department here...</option>
    @foreach($departments as $department)
    <option value="{{ $department->id }}" 
        {{ old('department_id', $ask->department->id) == $department->id ? 'selected' : ''}} 
        >
        {{ $department->department_name }}
    </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Instead of the above codes for the select option, I've used the "If condition" to get my result. But I'm trying to wrap it according to the codes in the above select option section.

> My approach with "IF" condition is here.

```
<select name="department_id" id="department_id" class="form-control">
<option disabled selected>Select Department here...</option>
@foreach($departments as $department)
<option value="{{ $department->id }}" 
    @if($ask->department === null)
        {{ old('department_id') }}
    @elseif($ask->department->id == $department->id)
        selected
    @endif
    >
    {{ $department->department_name }}
</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: `old('department_id', $ask->department ? $ask->department->id : null)` - Just check that `$ask->department` is present before trying to access `->id`. Or, if you're on PHP 8 or above, you might be able to use the Null Safe Operator: https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-nullsafe-operator

Comment: @Tim Lewis: Thanks for your fast reply, which efficiently fixed my problem. You can post this as an answer, then I can accept it. But I have a miner problem, according to my edited section which is the last code fraction at the bottom of the question, I can directly access the id from the department. Why is that?

Comment: You're welcome! But I posted that as a comment for a reason  I voted to close this question instead. There are already _tons_ of questions on Stackoverflow addressing this common issue, which essentially boils down to an error on your end (i.e. you forgot to write safe code).

Comment: @Tim Lewis: I appreciate your concern. If I am not bothering you could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong to avoid safe code? What should I do to improve the safety of the codes and where? I'm still learning.

Comment: No worries! What I mean by "safe" code is code that cannot fail if your data is in a bad spot. For example, writing `$ask->department->id` is not safe, as your code fails when `$ask->department` is `null`. Adding `$ask->department ? $ask->department->id : null` (or `$ask->department->id ?? null`, etc.) _is_ safe, as you have taken steps to ensure that even if it is `null`, it won't fail. Other approaches are using something like `$ask = Ask::has('department')->findOrFail($id)`, then `$ask->department->id`. That code cannot fail, as `$ask` will trigger a 404 if it doesn't have a department 

Comment: *"I can directly access the id from the department. Why is that?"* - In response to that, `$department` is coming from `@foreach($departments as $department)`. You can access `$department->id` without issue as A) `$department` is a Model, which _should_ have an `id`, and B) it's not nested. `$department->id` is going to be an `integer` (1, 2, etc.) or `null`. `$ask->department->id` _is nested_, and if `$ask->department` is `null`, you code is basically the same as writing `null->id`, which doesn't work (try it out! ; write `null->id` in PHP and it will fail)

Comment: Ah ha. I got what you mean. Thank you for your helpful introduction to this code. I'll be more careful with those patterns.